# Facebook is forcing use of its new messenger app, which is only supported on iOS7?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios, facebook

I'm running iOS 6.* on an IPhone 3Gs.

I noticed that Facebook was talking about redacting support for messaging inside the Facebook app...

This slightly bothered me, considering I am Quite happy using SMS for instant messaging, and Facebook for less frequent chat.

Regardless of how I feel, I now see that they are "Forcing" users over to their secondary Messenger application... which seems to be quite the ignorant move on their part-

When I went to the appstore to download the new messenger application... I found out that it was only supported in iOS7...

Will we really no longer be able to send and receive messages using Facebook on anything but the latest model phones?

Seeing as how they are doing the same on Android, and Seeing as how I wasn't offered to use a version of Facebook Messenger that was supported by iOS 6.*...

They can't really be considering dropping all support for any "older" model phone, can they? that is more than just stupid, it's plain cynical.

The tech enthusiast in me wants to believe their is a work around for this, or something I have simply over looked. but the conspiracy theorist in me wants to scream out about how this feels like they are trying to coerce mobile device owners to upgrade their phones.

It just doesn't feel fair, or even logical, that iOS 6.* should not support a basic messaging application.. especially one from a Company such as Facebook. they certainly have the wherewithal to support development of multiple versions of an applications.

are they really so out of touch that they could not possibly fork their app in the development repository, and build a release supporting the ios 6.* API/SDK?

**in short (and minus the rant), does anybody else have this concern? does anybody know how to work around this issue? does anybody actually know how to contact Facebook in order to complain?**

Comment: As written this seems to be more of a rant about Facebook and its apps strategy than an actual question. Feel free to rewrite it in a way which is in-line with the [FAQ] and have it re-opened.

Comment: typical. the rant was only posted in coagulation with the straightforward question: how can I work around this issue on iOS6? and this was clearly answered by Zero, without being based on opinion, and most certainly used facts. it also used references, in where he also answered my secondary question, which i only coined as a rant to prevent somebody from unnecessarily closing my question. why adding character to a question is dubbed negative on here, ill never know. instead of rewriting my question, ill let @zero have his points, and thank him for his legitimate effort. or delete it

Comment: moreover, I wanted to know the opinion of the community: whether I should be looking to upgrade my phone immediately... or in this hypothetical, might Facebook reverse its decision. this was also answered. and quite well I might add. must I really ask 3 different questions, all cookie-cutter and without any emotion whatsoever? looks like Forums need to make a comeback

Comment: The iPhone 3Gs is now over 5 years old, with five newer models released after it. In the fast-paced industry that is mobile phone software and apps, I am not in the least surprised that developers have started dropping support for the 3Gs. Apple has even stopped supporting the 3Gs for software updates - iOS7 is only compatible with iPhone 4 and up, and iOS8 is only compatible with iPhone 4s and up

Comment: as a developer who has worked on both IPhone and Android Applications, I still cannot see why it dropping support for something only a few years old is relevant in a fast paced industry. albeit, it has been a few years since my last iOS Project; even the most recent release of the Android Software Development Kit it mostly pliable and to a certain degree, backwards compatible with its predecessor. moreover, just like with Android, there is a hefty userbase for the older models, and in a fast paced industry, it makes *more* sense to provide support for something a few years old. most two cents.

Comment: not to mention, the only part which is essentially broken by this issue is the ability to send messages over Facebook. I somehow doubt the latest version of iOS contains something in its API that negates the ability of iOS6 users to communicate with their messaging platform and backend. we already know that with some apps, you can download old versions of applications for support purposes. facebook *must* have the capacity to fork the messaging application source code, and build any iOS7 dependant features into the latest version, while still providing long term support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mobile site will still allow you to send/receive messages in Safari and other browsers. It may also be that the version of the app you are using is so old that they cannot prevent the messenging functionality from working; you'll have to wait to see about that or dig up user comments on the topic from Europe, which was pushed into this model in the spring.

Considering that the public's response to this news has been almost uniformly negative, I think it's reasonable to suspect that this policy change may be reversed after the numbers are crunched and usage declines become obvious. The primary point of splitting the apps is to increase revenue by doubling the ads the users are forced to see; if people stop using the original app and refuse to download the messenger app, this plan backfires.

Comment: what doesn’t make sense to me is that the average user would now be splitting his time in the view port between both apps.. thus, wouldn’t the time spent viewing ads be the same? just a thought

Comment: It doesn't matter how long you view the ads, it matters how many ads you view. The more different pages you have to load and switch between, the more ads you load, and the more revenue they get

Comment: what i meant is that, say you are somebody who uses facebook X hours per day. you spend half that time viewing the news feed, and the other half sending and receiving messages. now that it is in two apps, you still spend the same time on "facebook". rather, now its simply divided by two apps. still the same amount of time on their service. I fail to see how this means you are loading more "pages". considering the majority of ads displayed directly inside the news feed? or targeted stories? etc? AFAIK